# No such table when creating the table with the name of deleted table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I create table with DBHelper class. I delete it using this method of DBHelper:

```
public void delete()
{
    SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(new File(String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath(getTableName()))));
    getWritableDatabase().execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + getTableName());

    Log.d("table", "table deleted");
}
```

When I create new table with the same name I want to get data from it (I fill when on the stage of creating). If I create cursor it says that there is no such table.

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: You can actually create the whole DB with any tool you like and ship it with your app. That way you don't have to create it in your code

Comment: You posted code that is not needed. Where is the code that creates the table?

Comment: @forpas, doesn't it create table in method onCreate() of DBHelper if table not exists? Or I understand smth wrong? Couldn't you tell when the table creates?

Comment: No it does not. The onCreate() is called once the 1st time you run the app and call getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase.

Comment: @forpas, so, what is the right way of creating table?

Comment: table name != database file name. You're trying to delete a database file named after a table name.

Comment: Ok, thanks to everybody. I got lots of usefful information.